# What is the name of this famous capital city?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

In a recently unknown land, roads are rapidly being built by volunteers. There is no construction experience required, and seasoned road builders keep a watchful eye. Exits are abundant, offering frontage roads, detours, and highways to far away places. It is truly a revolutionary system of transportation.

The roads provide utility that the citizens of this land now rely on. However, some also use the roads for sport, racing each other to exotic destinations. With myriad paths to the finish, each racer must anticipate future exits and above all, never backtrack.

The roads also have a unique quality which can be easily demonstrated. When asked how to get to the capital city, most locals will respond with a grin, "Just keep turning!"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The capital city is

> Wikipedia's page on Philosophy.

Built by volunteers and overseen by experienced builders.

> Exits are abundant, offering frontage roads, detours, and highways to far away places.

refers to

> links to other articles.

The paragraph

> The roads provide utility that the citizens of this land now rely on. However, some also use the roads for sport, racing each other to exotic destinations. With myriad paths to the finish, each racer must anticipate future exits and above all, never backtrack.

refers to

> both the use of Wikipedia for its intended purpose, and the noble sport of [wikiracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikirace).

And finally,

> The roads also have a unique quality which can be easily demonstrated. When asked how to get to the capital city, most locals will respond with a grin, "Just keep turning!"

refers to

> if you just keep clicking, you'll end up there sooner or later.

Comment: This sounds good, but in the land of wikipedia all roads lead not to Rome, but to.... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Getting_to_Philosophy

Comment: So the unknown land is Wikipedia and the capital city is Philosophy, then. Maybe he should update his answer to answer the question asked instead of "what is the unknown land?".

Comment: Aren't the articles for Reality, Existence, and Ontology equally valid capital cities? Is this a South Africa situation?

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> [Open street maps](http://www.openstreetmap.org)?

In a recently unknown land, roads are rapidly being built by volunteers. There is no construction experience required, and seasoned road builders keep a watchful eye.

> Open street maps can be updated by anyone that signs up to it, I've done a couple of changes myself when the local post office moved. When a change is submitted, many "seasoned" map builders check it over.

Exits are abundant, offering frontage roads, detours, and highways to far away places. It is truly a revolutionary system of transportation.

> It's a map, it contains all of these things, and because it's open source, it's revolutionary

The roads provide utility that the citizens of this land now rely on. However, some also use the roads for sport, racing each other to exotic destinations. With myriad paths to the finish, each racer must anticipate future exits and above all, never backtrack.

> Games have been created with the open street maps: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Games

The roads also have a unique quality which can be easily demonstrated. When asked how to get to the capital city, most locals will respond with a grin, "Just keep turning!"

> The maps are unique in many ways. There are various different layers that can be used to view different data, for example clicking the link at the top should supply a list of 5 available layers. Because it's open source there is no home (capital) for it, for example Google maps is Google, Bing maps is Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> the brain?

It fits the description:

> Scientist are only just now discovering the depths of the mind.
>  The roads mentioned are the neural network.
>  The far away places are the other parts of the body.
>  Signal pulses should not backtrack.
>  It's revolutionary indeed!
>  And of course, it's a "Capital" city!

(I cannot explain every line as of yet)

Answer (score -1):

Are you

> The letter o in cursive?

Explanation

> In cursive letters are connected with long curved flourishes much like exits and detours on a road. Since each of these connections will look slightly different it is like having roads all leading to different places. To make a capital O in cursive you would just keep turning and make the circle a bit larger.

Comment: This makes no sense. How do the citizens, racing, detours, exits,or the city fit in?

Comment: The city is a sentence, the exits and detours are the flourishes between words, racing is writing, and the citizens could be the author or the letters.

Comment: You said it was JUST the letter O. There aren't "myriad paths" to race on and supposedly the entire text describes the city, so none of those clues fit.

Comment: The passage does not specifically state it is about the capital city. It's located in a recently unknown land not a recently unknown capital city

Comment: The answer is not a letter in the alphabet.